# Improving the appearance of Chakra UI Locale Switcher in Next.js 13

Tags: typescript, next.js, next.js13, chakra-ui, next-intl

I'm using Next.js 13 with Chakra UI for my app, and I've implemented internationalization by following this [guide](https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/getting-started/app-router-client-components). The complete example from the guide is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/amannn/next-intl/blob/main/examples/example-next-13/src/components/LocaleSwitcher.tsx). I've adapted the example to use Chakra UI components, but I'm facing styling issues.

Here's my `LocaleSwitcher` component:

```
'use client';

import { ChangeEvent } from 'react';
import { Box, Select, Text, useColorModeValue } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { useLocale } from 'next-intl';
import { usePathname, useRouter } from 'next-intl/client';

export const LocaleSwitcher = () => {
  const locale = useLocale();
  const router = useRouter();
  const pathname = usePathname();

  const colorModeBg = useColorModeValue('brand.100', 'brand.700');

  const switchLanguage = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    const nextLocale = event.target.value;
    router.replace(pathname, { locale: nextLocale });
  };

  return (
    <Box position="relative" color={colorModeBg}>
      <Select size="sm" defaultValue={locale} onChange={switchLanguage}>
        {['en', 'bg'].map((cur) => (
          <option key={cur} value={cur}>
            {cur.toUpperCase()}
          </option>
        ))}
      </Select>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

The appearance of the `Select` component is terrible:

[image]

As visible in the image, there are undesired white borders around the dropdown. I'd appreciate any advice on:

- How to remove or customize the white borders.
- General improvements on the component's design using Chakra UI.

How can I remove those white borders, or do you have a better idea how to do it?

### Edit

```
'use client';

import {
  Box,
  Button,
  Menu,
  MenuButton,
  MenuList,
  MenuItem,
  useColorModeValue,
} from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { ChevronDownIcon } from '@chakra-ui/icons';
import { useLocale } from 'next-intl';
import { usePathname, useRouter } from 'next-intl/client';

export const LocaleSwitcher = () => {
  const locale = useLocale();
  const router = useRouter();
  const pathname = usePathname();

  const switchLanguage = (nextLocale: string) => {
    router.replace(pathname, { locale: nextLocale });
  };

  return (
    <Menu>
      {({ isOpen }) => (
        <>
          <MenuButton
            as={Button}
            rightIcon={<ChevronDownIcon />}
            variant="ghost"
            isActive={isOpen}
          >
            {locale.toUpperCase()}
          </MenuButton>
          <MenuList>
            {['en', 'bg'].map((cur) => (
              <MenuItem key={cur} onClick={() => switchLanguage(cur)}>
                {cur.toUpperCase()}
              </MenuItem>
            ))}
          </MenuList>
        </>
      )}
    </Menu>
  );
};
```

[image]

This looks much better but I'm sure the code can be refactored.